# Firebase realtime database get Online Friends

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am not sure if this is possible in fire base as I wish,
My database is

```
    User_ID: ID
        online:true/false
        friends: 
               ID: Name 
               ID: Name
```

User login in, retrieve his information including friends Ids.

My question can I get All users with some IDs (User friend Ids) who have online true.

Looks like 2 queries:  (Where friends ids(multiple ids) = ??? and online = true)

I have workaround solution for this but I don't like it As i have to get  all Online users (friends and none friends) and keep only friend, in this case I will retrieve data which I dont want in this case.

Comment: If you have to make queries you should use Cloud Firestore Database , it would make easier for you .

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use just single query  yes there is an method for realtime database

databaseRef.orderByChild("online").equalTo(true);

And this will return all the keys/items of parent from databse which have online:true child:value under them

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-complex-queries

Comment: Thanks but this will return all online users, I need all onine users who is in my friend lists.

Comment: That's an double query .... You can design custom logic in your application like first of query your database I.e who is online then filter out the data with ur frnds list using comparison logic make an array out of it pass it to recycler view in case of android else pass it to ur crud app in case of web which is really a lengthy process. Else I will suggest go for firestore instead. It is similar to implement and u can fire up double queries.

Comment: One more solution but I'll not suggest it is